# Proving $\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3=n}{n\choose a_1, a_2, a_3}=3^n$

Tags: combinatorics

I need some hints where to start to prove that

$$\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3=n}{n\choose a_1, a_2, a_3}=3^n$$

Comment: This cannot be right. Since $a_1+a_2+a_3=n$ always, all summands are $\binom nn=1$. So the question boils down to showing there are $3^n$ terms in the sum, but this is not true, even for $n=2$ (there are $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2$ terms).

Comment: Since the lower indices must sum to the upper, we only need two indices in the trinomial coefficient:$$\binom{n}{a_1,a_2}$$ is how I usually write the trinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint** What is the coefficient of $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}z^{a_3}$ in $(x+y+z)^n$.

What happens if you set $x=y=z=1$?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{a_1}y^{a_2}z^{a_3}$ in $(x+y+z)^n$ is not $n \choose{a_1+a_2+a_3}$.

Comment: @SteveKass True, but that is most probably a typo in the problem ;)

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ a set with cardinal $n$ then the number of maps $X\to\{1,2,3\}$ is $3^n$ and each map is defined if we associate the elements $x_1,\ldots,x_{a_1}$ of $X$ to $1$ and  $y_{1},\ldots,y_{a_2}$ of $X$ to $2$ and  $z_1,\ldots,z_{a_3}$ of $X$ to $3$ where 
$$X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_{a_1},y_{1},\ldots,y_{a_2},z_1,\ldots,z_{a_3}\}$$
so we have
$$\sum_{a_1+a_2+a_3=n}{n\choose a_1,a_2,a_3}=3^n$$

Comment: I love the way you answered very neat questions Sami. Sometimes, pluses are not enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Use the multinomial theorem by substitution

Comment: There aren't any multinomial coefficients in the question (yet).

Comment: Substitute like, $a_1=a_2=a_3=1$

Comment: That gives $\binom3{1+1+1}=\binom33=1$.

Comment: The multinomial theorem states that:
$$(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k)^n=\sum\cdots$$
thus, makes it $(3)^n$

Comment: The question has now been adapted to your answer, so my comments no longer apply.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** When $a_1+a_2+a_3=n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{a_1,a_2,a_3}
&=\frac{n!}{a_1!a_2!(n-a_1-a_2)!}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{n!}{a_1!(n-a_1)!}\frac{(n-a_1)!}{a_2!(n-a_1-a_2)!}\\[6pt]
&=\binom{n}{a_1}\binom{n-a_1}{a_2}
\end{align}
$$
Sum in $a_2$ then sum in $a_1$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

This is a repetition of the answer of Sami Ben Roundhane, so if you feel like upvoting, upvote his instead.

There are $3^n$ words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$. We count the words another way.

For any non-negative integers $p$, $q$, and $r$ such that $p+q+r=n$, there are $\binom{n}{p,q,r}$ words that have exactly  $p$ $a$'s, $q$ $b$'s, and $r$ $c$'s. For the **locations** of the $p$ $a$'s, $q$ $b$'s, and $r$ $c$'s can be chosen in $\binom{n}{p,q,r}$ ways. Summing over all $p$, $q$, and $r$ such that $p+q+r=n$ gives us a count of all the words.

Comment: You deserve (+1) since you put the idea in a concrete example

Comment: This does not repeat, but corrects both the question and the answer. Am I the only person who can perceive the difference between $\binom n{p,q,r}$ and $\binom n{p+q+r}$??

Comment: See @marc-van-leeuwen's comment to the original post. You have proved something about $n\choose{p,\,q,\,r}$ where the original post contains  $n\choose{p+q+r}$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: I didn't notice the $+$'s, "saw" only what **should** be there. With $+$'s it is of course wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3}\ =\ n}{n \choose a_{1},\ a_{2},\ a_3}
     = 3^{n}:\  {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large
> \sum_{a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3}\ =\ n}{n \choose a_{1},\ a_{2},\ a_3}}
> =\sum_{a_{1}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{2}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{3}=0}^{\infty}
> {n! \over a_{1}!\ a_{2}!\ a_{3}!}\,\delta_{a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3},n}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{a_{1}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{2}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{a_{3}=0}^{\infty}
> {n! \over a_{1}!\ a_{2}!\ a_{3}!}\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
> {1 \over z^{-a_{1} - a_{2} - a_{3} + n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{n! \over z^{n + 1}}\,\pars{%
> \sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}{z^{a} \over a!}}^{3}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}n!\,{\expo{3z} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}n!\ {3^{k} \over k!}\
> \overbrace{\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,{z^{k} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
> ^{\ds{\delta_{kn}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\LARGE 3^{n}}
> \end{align}